# How to transpose specific rows into columns

Tags: sql, hive

I am doing a count of accounts for each month, based on country and product.  I end up with a table that shows each month, the country and the product, with the count for that month.  I want to be able to pull from that table each product and country, then have a column for each month with the count.

```
+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
|  plcmnt_mnth  | product_code | ctry_cd | accounts_placed |
+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
| August        | Lending      | AR      |             751 |
| August        | Charge       | MX      |            2137 |
| August        | Charge       | AR      |             240 |
| August        | Lending      | MX      |            3307 |
| July          | Charge       | AR      |              67 |
| July          | Lending      | AR      |             122 |
| July          | Charge       | MX      |             977 |
| July          | Lending      | MX      |             694 |
| Pre-June 2019 | Charge       | AR      |              16 |
| Pre-June 2019 | Lending      | AR      |              25 |
| Pre-June 2019 | Charge       | MX      |              76 |
| Pre-June 2019 | Lending      | MX      |              72 |
+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
```

I have tried using CASE WHEN for the plcmnt_mnth, I have tried to use coalesce but cant seem to get it right.  I have also tried looking at other questions on here about transposing but can't seem to find one that fits with what I am trying to do.

This is the code I am using to pull the data.  It is pulling from a table that is a list of all accounts.

```
select plcmnt_mnth, product_code, ctry_cd,  count(acct) as accounts_placed
from cj_test_placements
group by plcmnt_mnth, product_code, ctry_cd;
```

I would like to see a new column for each month.  The table this is pulled from is set to label any date before June 2019 as Pre-June 2019, each month after that is counted per month.  I would like to be able to do this so that once we get to October and there is a count for October it adds another column and then November etc.

```
+--------------+---------+---------------+------+--------+
| product_code | ctry_cd | Pre-June 2019 | July | August |
+--------------+---------+---------------+------+--------+
| Charge       | AR      |            16 |   67 |    240 |
| Lending      | AR      |            25 |  122 |    751 |
| Charge       | MX      |            76 |  977 |   2137 |
| Lending      | MX      |            72 |  694 |   3307 |
+--------------+---------+---------------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would implement the `case` statements

```
select 
product_code, 
ctry_code, 
max(case when accounts_placement_mnth='Pre-June 2019' then accounts_placed end) as Pre-June-2019,
max(case when accounts_placement_mnth='July' then accounts_placed end) as July,
max(case when accounts_placement_mnth='August' then accounts_placed end) as August
from cj_test_placements
group by product_code, ctry_code;
```

Comment: This was the method I had attempted with the CASE statment and it does give me the columns for each month, but I still have a row for every product_code and ctry_cd.  so instead of one row showing 'Charge' 'AR' ' 16','67','240'  I get three rows with a count in pre-june 2019 then july and august blank, then anotehr with pre-june blank a count in july then august blank.  I would like to have the coutns show up on one row .

Comment: Thank you @String once I added the MAX it really cleaned it up and looked to do what I was trying to try.  Another question I have is, if I add the months for the whole year, October, November, December, it picks them up as blank is there an easy way to remove the column for future months?  If not I can handle this by pasting into excel then hiding in a table.

Comment: @Sotark I think you are seeing blanks because you don't have any accounts placed for those months There is no easy way to show the columns in a dynamic manner. You could rewrite the query to say  then  'Not Applicable' for those months if you wish to communicate that.